# React 16 setstate in componentdidmount but throws null error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my whole code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

var Chart = require('./Chart');

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({      
      data1: [
        {id: '5fbmzmtc', x: 7, y: 41, z: 6},
        {id: 's4f8phwm', x: 11, y: 45, z: 9}
      ],
      domain: {x: [0, 30], y: [0, 100]}
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (        
      <div>
        <div className="bottom-right-svg">
          <Chart data={this.state.data1} domain={this.state.domain} />
        </div>
      </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see I set state in componentDidMount() but this.state is null error.

*TypeError: this.state is null* in render() function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because you are returning this.state null for the first time .

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize `this.state` in your `constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
}
```

Comment: I added your code but meet such error. "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. "

Comment: It likely means you're passing incorrect data to `Chart`

Comment: I think it's another issue

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a wise idea to use `setState` function inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. Just initialize it inside constructor or if you are using modern ES, try following approach:

**Edit**: Note that probably every linter will throw you a warning if you use `setState` inside `componentDidMount` hook. However, it's not an anti-pattern, but can cause unexpected behavior.

From **React** docs:
*"Calling `setState()` in this method will trigger an extra rendering (...) Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues"*. You **can** use it, but the question is if your component can afford one additional, extra render?

More reading: https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-call-setstate-immediately-after-componentdidmount-in-react-cim5vz8kn01flek53aqa22mby

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = {      
     data1: [
       {id: '5fbmzmtc', x: 7, y: 41, z: 6},
       {id: 's4f8phwm', x: 11, y: 45, z: 9},
     ],
       domain: {x: [0, 30], y: [0, 100]},
   };

   render() {
     return (        
       <div>
         <div className="bottom-right-svg">
           <Chart data={this.state.data1} domain={this.state.domain} />
         </div>
       </div>      
     );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I exported App as code shows but meet another error following your code. "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in."

Comment: I love this community, being downvoted everytime I use some modern solution. Guys, it's 2017, ES6/ES7 are here since 3 years. Please get used to it.

Comment: @Guru I've written that it **might** not work for you if you are not using modern ES (ESNext). Declaring state this way is still in beta, but it's being commonly used in the newest React apps. Feel free to get Babel and embrace all features from ESNext.

Comment: Downvoted for blanketly stating it's unwise to `setState` in CDM, which contradicts the React docs. This example doesn't need CDM since its data is static, but it's not an anit-pattern to `setState` here.

Comment: @lux Thank you for showing up. Anyways - every linter on this world will shout if you declare `setState` function inside `componentDidMount` function. Just type *setState inside `componentDidMount` function* in Google, you will get dozens of topics where it's clearly said to avoid it.

Comment: Using a Github user's custom linting rules to determine framework behavior is not ideal. Check the docs for yourself: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: @lux *"Calling `setState()` in this method will trigger an extra rendering (...) Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues"* - I've been working with React for a really long time and trust me, sometimes your components are so heavy that you just can't afford an additional, extra render.

Comment: Well let's quote the **whole** line if we're honest about this technology: "_Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but it is guaranteed to flush during the same tick._". So being cautious with pattern implementation !== never use.

Comment: @lux I agree, but I haven't said *never use* or it's illegal to use it that way. Just wrote that it isn't wise and I wouldn't suggest it. That's all, actually.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you work with async data? Wondering how you populate state from an API call if  you don't utilize CDM. Always open to new patterns.

Comment: Maybe next time don't take downvotes so personally, it clearly affected your day. Also, I was giving you an out for asking about async since it's clear you don't have experience w it and React.

Comment: Great edit you posted, here's an excerprt: "The official documentation site for React recommends multiple times that ajax and subsequent setState calls should be done in componentDidMount. I can find no other reliable source that suggests this is a bad practice." But hey, I'm sure once you start working with async, you'll come around.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to set the state in `componentDidMount` ?

Your component has already rendered once before going to `componentDidMount`, that's why you have this problem.

You should init the state in the constructor instead.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

var Chart = require('./Chart');

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {      
        data1: [
          {id: '5fbmzmtc', x: 7, y: 41, z: 6},
          {id: 's4f8phwm', x: 11, y: 45, z: 9}
        ],
        domain: {x: [0, 30], y: [0, 100]}
      };
    }

  render() {
    return (        
      <div>
        <div className="bottom-right-svg">
          <Chart data={this.state.data1} domain={this.state.domain} />
        </div>
      </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```